# What does LS stand for in LSSerializer ? Say as in org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer

Tags: java, xmlserializer

Like XMLSerializer we have LSSerializer in Java. What does LS indicate in it?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at `org.w3c.dom.ls` package you can find a class `DOMImplementationLS` with description:  `contains the factory methods for creating Load and Save objects`.

It can be safely assumed that `LS` stands from `Load` and `Save`.
You can also see that in whole `dom` package and its subpackages they start most of their classes with subpackage name as a prefix to class name, that's a matter of style only.

Answer (score 2):

I think LS indicates LocalSolver or Load and Save.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html

https://www.localsolver.com/docs/last/java/localsolver/LSException.html